# yaws unicode symbols in {html, ...}

Tags: unicode, erlang, yaws

Why {html, "доуч"++[1076,1086,1091,1095]} in yaws-page gives me next error:

```
Yaws process died: {badarg,[{erlang,list_to_binary,
                                    [[[[208,180,208,190,209,131,209,135,1076,
                                        1086,1091,1095]],
                                        ...
```

"доуч" = [1076,1086,1091,1095] -> gives me exact match, but how yaws translate 2-byte per elem list in two times longer list with 1 byte per elem for "доуч", but doesnt do it for [1076,1086,1091,1095]. Is there some internal represintation of unicode data involed?

I want to output to the web pages lists like [1076,1086,1091,1095], but it crushed.

Answer (score 1):

Erlang source files only support the ISO-LATIN-1 charset. The Erlang console can accept Unicode characters, but to enter them inside a source code file, you need to use this syntax:

```
K = "A weird K: \x{a740}".
```

See http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following to make it work:

```
{html, "доуч"++ binary_to_list(unicode:characters_to_binary([1076,1086,1091,1095]))}
```

**Why it fails?**

In a bit more detail, the `list_to_binary` fails because it is trying to convert each item in the list to a byte, which it cannot do because each value in `[1076,1086,1091,1095]` would take more than a byte.

**What is going on?**

`[1076,1086,1091,1095]` is a pure unicode string representation of `"доуч"`. Yaws tries to convert the string (list) into a binary string directly using `list_to_binary` and thus fails. Since each unicode character can take more than one byte, we need to convert it into a byte array. This can be done using:

```
unicode:characters_to_binary([1076,1086,1091,1095]). 
<<208,180,208,190,209,131,209,135>>
```

This can now be safely converted back and forth between list and binary representations. See  [unicode](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html) for more details.

You can convert back to unicode as follows:

```
unicode:characters_to_list(<<208,180,208,190,209,131,209,135>>).
[1076,1086,1091,1095]
```